# is CPU virtualization needed to run Android Virtual Device?

Tags: android-sdk, virtualization, avd-manager

My Dell Laptop has **Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor T6400** (2M Cache, 2.00 GHz, 800 MHz FSB) CPU which has no virtualization support.

http://ark.intel.com/products/40479/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T6400-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

Above link says :

Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x) ‡ no

My basic hello world Android application using eclipse not able to open AVD.
I can not see device window opening.

is that CPU visualization problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can always try to use an ARM VM instead of an x86, because the error log you provided states that: `x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!`. So try this and report back. Keep in mind that QEMU (used for ARM on x86) is very slow and eats CPU cycles like crazy.

Answer (score 0):

While running AVD I got the error:

```
[2015-05-04 23:02:01 - TESTapplication] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'TEST_5.1_5.1.1'
[2015-05-04 23:02:01 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
[2015-05-04 23:02:01 - Emulator] Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
[2015-05-04 23:02:01 - Emulator] CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

and I got the thread which talk about this error.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720064/hax-kernel-module-is-not-installed

so Conclusion is my Intel Core to Duo T6400 CPU do not support hardware virtualization and will not be able to run AVD. I need to get new Laptop to get this CPU function and AVD running.

Comment: Please include this information in your question and not as an answer.